# If $W \approx W'$ and $V \approx V'$ then $L(W,V) \approx L(W',V')$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Exercise: Let's $W,W',V,V'$ vector spaces over a field $F$, with $\dim W =n$ and $\dim V = n$. Suppose that $W \approx W'$ and $V \approx V'$ then  $L(W,V) \approx L(W',V)$ (Show an isomorphism).

Well, I know that $\dim L(W,V) = n\cdot m = \dim L(W',V')$. Then they are isomorphics, but I need to prove showing an isomorphism.

May you give me a tip?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_V : V \to V'$ and $f_W : W \to W'$ be isomorphisms.

Show that the function $\Phi : \mathcal{L}(W,V) \to \mathcal{L}(W',V')$ defined by 
$$\Phi(T) = f_V \circ T \circ (f_W)^{-1}$$
is an isomorphism. Luck!

Comment: of course, thank you!